# Failed when boot with Ubuntu On Surface Laptop3

Tags: boot, windows-10

After install Ubuntu22.04.3 on Surface Laptop3 along with Windows10（win BitLocker function closed before Ubuntu install），

- Stopped at "Win Logo" when boot with Ubuntu
- Stopped at "Win Logo" when boot with USB Storage(USB-boot-disk Plugged-In)
- Success to win desktop when boot with Windows Boot Manager

What should i do？

Comment: Is this a reboot or a cold boot? It's documented at https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Surface-Laptop-3 that Surface devices might have reboot problems. Is secure boot properly disabled?

Comment: Yes, it happened when reboot or cold boot every times.
I tried to disable the secure boot, nothing change but a red ribbon on the win logo interface, and an unlocked white lock in the middle of the ribbon.

Comment: Please try installing the linux-surface PPA and kernel, and selecting it. If the problem persists with it, then open a issue on the linux-surface GitHub repo.